# AWS lambda function deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have developed a lambda function which hits API url and getting the data in Json Format. So need to use modules/libraries like requests which is not available in AWS online editor using Python 2.7.

So need to upload the code in Zip file, How we can do step by step to deploy Lambda function from windows local server to AWS console. What are the requirements?

Comment: Did you check this [lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)?

Comment: Thanks It was helpful..I was trying in windows locally but to deploy the lambda packages it is easy to create the package using AWS linux instance virtual environment.http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html#deployment-pkg-for-virtualenv

Comment: Lambda uses Amazon Linux as the Operating System. Use the same to create deployment packages.

Comment: Thanks..I am able to create deployment packages successfully.Thanks a lot for quick response.

Answer (score 1):

You could use code build, which will build your code on the aws linux envoirnment. Then it wont matter if the envoirnment is windows or linux.
code build will put the artifacts directly on s3, from there you can directly upload it to lambda.